# Should I implement IDispose for UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I wrote an usercontrol which show the Google Admod to my page. this control is simple with only 1 grid (LayoutRoot), 1 image (get random from my DB) to show when can't get the ad. On each page I have this control, I request a new ad and add to this LayoutRoot. Problem is, create this usercontrol repeatly (when navigate between pages has this control ) cause memory leak (I'm not sure because of the background image or the google admob). So now I want to implement this control to Idispose, but I'm still confused:

1. Can I (and do I need to) implement Idispose for UserControl ?
2. If I do, will my page call the dispose of this control when the page is finalized ?
3. What is the correct way to implement IDispose ? follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) I wrote a test, but I'm not sure if this'is correct ?

   ```
   bool disposed = false;
   public void Dispose()
   {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (disposed)
           return;

       if (disposing)
       {
           // I'm don't know what to put here ?
       }
       adview.FailedToReceiveAd -= adview_FailedToReceiveAd;
       adview.ReceivedAd -= adview_ReceivedAd;
       adview = null;
       request = null;
       imgMyAd.Source = null;
       imgMyAd = null;
       disposed = true;
   }

   ~AdPro()
   {
       Dispose(false);
   }
   ```

here's my UserControl:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black" Height="60">
        <Image x:Name="imgMyAd" Height="{Binding Height ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                Width="{Binding Width ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}" Stretch="Fill"/>            
        <Grid x:Name="AdMob">                          
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

c#

```
public partial class AdPro : UserControl
{
    public AdPro()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.AdControlD;
        imgMyAd.Source = GetRandomBGImg();     // get the image from my server
        if (App.IsNetworkAvailable)          // check if internet's available
        {                 
            AddAdtoGrid();                
        }
    }

    AdRequest request = null;
    AdView adview = null;

    public void AddAdtoGrid()
    {
        adview = new AdView()
        {                
            AdUnitID="xxxxxx‏",
            Format = AdFormats.Banner,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        AdMob.Children.Add(adview);
        request = new AdRequest();
        request.ForceTesting = true;
        adview.FailedToReceiveAd += adview_FailedToReceiveAd;
        adview.ReceivedAd += adview_ReceivedAd;
        adview.LoadAd(request);
    }

    void adview_ReceivedAd(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("get ad success");            
    }

    void adview_FailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("get ad failed: " + e.ErrorCode);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wpf `UserControl` is pretty high-level object. You may implement `IDisposable` for it, but it might be worth to simply use `Load` (to create) / `Unload` (to dispose) events to handle any unmanaged resources.

Comment: If I use unload event, when I navigate from a page using this usercontrol, the unload event fired, so when I navigate back my usercontrol's gone.

Comment: Yep, it should gone after `Unload` event. And what is the problem? If you need some data to stay when *control is disposed*, then you have to implement it somewhere in some class, which will get data, provide it for `UserControl` (when its created, aka `Load`ed), keep data between back/forward-ing and dispose it when you think it must be disposed.

Comment: What I mean is, for example, I'm at page A with this usercontrol, then I navigate to page B. This time page A's still in the navigate call stack and can restore from navigationservice.goback(). What I want is get rid of the usercontrol resource only when page A is dispose too.